# Как в столбце фрейма Pandas сложить некоторые ячейки по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

У меня есть датафрейм Pandas, где необходимо сложить по определенному столбцу часть его строк. Причем сделать это следует не произвольно а, двигаясь по порядку вниз, отмерять заданное переменной **order** количество строк.

Итак, сколько строк брать в сумму, подскажет определяемый пользователем показатель **order**. В нашем случае `order=3`, значит, складываем по 3 строки. Пока у меня получена исходная таблица. Размышляю над суммированием. Буду благодарен за идеи. Думаю пока в сторону группировки по строкам, но затрудняюсь в реализации.

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

order = 3
y_0 = 0
koefs_list = [3,4,5]
parameters_list = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]

df = pd.DataFrame({"params":parameters_list, "koefs":koefs_list*int(len(parameters_list)/len(koefs_list))})
df["res"] = df["params"]*df["koefs"]+y_0
print(df)
```

В выводе мне необходимо сложить значения по столбцу `res`:

```
    params  koefs  res
0       1      3    3
1       1      4    4
2       1      5    5
3       2      3    6
4       2      4    8
5       2      5   10
6       3      3    9
7       3      4   12
8       3      5   15
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что вы хотите видеть на выходе при этих данных, какие значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще у вас и так данные уже разбиты на нужные тройки и можно сделать так:

```py
print(df.groupby('params')['res'].sum())
```

Но если всё же на это нельзя ориентироваться, то можно просто посчитать элементы с делением на цело на `order`:

```py
df.groupby(pd.Series(range(df.shape[0]))//order)['res'].sum()
```

В обоих случаях вывод будет такой:

```
0    12
1    24
2    36
Name: res, dtype: int64
```

Comment: на выходе мне нужен столбец, в котором просуммированы по 3 значения из колонки `res`

Comment: @AlexKazantsev так я сделал то, что вы хотели или нет?

Comment: да, все отлично - так надо. Благодарю